# How do Google,Yahoo and other mail services secure passwords?

Tags: security, password-management

- How do Google,Yahoo and other top level mail services secure passwords?
- What technology they are using for securing and storing passwords?
- How do they manage mail passwords ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I don't believe that any of us can say definitively what any of those companies are using, but it is highly likely that *all* of them are using some form of [one-way hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) to store the passwords. Using any other type of password storage would be highly irresponsible. [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) and [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) are frequently used for this type of hashing.

As far as what they're using to manage passwords, it's probably safe to say that they're all using a custom-built account system that interfaces with their back-end mail delivery and transport systems.

Comment: You can probably get a pretty good idea how Google works by looking at their [provisioning API](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/gdata_provisioning_api_v2.0_reference.html).  GoogleApps passwords set via the API can be stored as an unsalted SHA1 or MD5.